# How to display public and private data on a Google Calendar that members can subscribe to

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to figure out the best approach to doing this. Here's the scenario I have.

Using a company Google Calendar and its API, I want to be able to:

- Add public events that anyone can see.
- Add private events that users logged into my website can see.
- Allow users logged into my website to add/edit private events.
- Allow users logged in to be able to subscribe to the calendar.
- But not allow just anyone to be able to subscribe to the calendar because of the private events.
- I do not wish to have to manage "sharing" the calendar with individuals.

Basically, I don't know if I should just use two separate calendars, one that is public and one that is private, and then on the private calendar "share" the calendar with that person's email pragmatically, or use one calendar that is public and then somehow hope that the public calendar doesn't end up in Google's search engine and/or someone outside of my logged in users.

I hope this was clear as to what I am trying to accomplish. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Is the companies calendar  under a workspace account?

Comment: I am using a service account to create a calendar from the API.

Comment: Yes but service accounts only work with Google calendar if its a google workspace account.  With domain wide delegation configured